# How to setup SSH access to a docker container?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, docker

I am running a docker container within an EC2 instance, How to ssh into the docker container directly without having to login to the container host i.e the EC2 instance here everytime?

Comment: Do you have an IP address you can reach your container?

Comment: does your container run a ssh server?

Comment: No SSH server in the docker container currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There an example of setting up SSH service on the docker documentation.

https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/

Once you have the IP of the host and the port mapped to port 22 of the container, you should be able to ssh